# Linux bash commands in android 4.1.2?

Tags: linux, bash, command, android

Is there a way to run linux bash commands in android (particularly 4.1.2 rooted or not rooted)? Will it void the warranty from phone manufacturers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I use [Terminal Emulator for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en). This works well for me, and comes pre-installed in Cyanogenmod. I particularly like pairing it with [WiFi Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.volosyukivan&hl=en), so I can use a real keyboard. These are both open source, although I've provided Google Play links. This drops you into `sh` by default, but I have `bash` installed too.

As for voiding warranty, you'll have to check your specific manufacturer's warranty.